# Drag Drop UIImageView into subView - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I'm newbie to Swift and trying to drag a UIImageView into UiView, I have three UIViews i have to drag the UIImageView into any three UIViews , not anywhere.

I have tried touchesBegan, touchesEnded method, but drag drop is not on inside this any of 3 UIViews.

[image]

Please anyone give me skeleton to drop the UIImageView to anyone of three UIViews,

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: `touchesBegan` have a set of `touches` which you can use to find the location of the touch, same for touchesMoved and touchesEnded. UIView have a hit test `point(inside:with:)` to check if a point is within the view. `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so that method can be called too.

Comment: If that is not accurate enough, `UIView` have a property called `frame` which is a `CGRect`. `CGRect` have a method called `intersect(:CGRect)`, during touchesEnded you can check all three `UIView`s with the `UIImageView` for `intersect`

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I have added the image, please check

Comment: @US-1234 Your wording is not clear. So re-structure your question as described by [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) this link

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` and all `UIView`s probably share the same `superView`, if you want to put `UIImageView` inside of `UIView` you need to move it. I mean you need to remove it from `superView` and add it to the view beneath it (if they intersect)

Here's what you're gonna do:

1. When User touches (pans) the `UIImageView`, move it to `superView` (If It's already there, it's ok, if It's in one of `UIView`s, you need to remove it from them, and add it to superView)
2. When user touch has ended, `UIGestureRecognizer` will also inform you about it, at that moment check if there's any `UIView`s beneath your `UIImageView` or not, if not do nothing else remove it from `superView` and add the view beneath it.

There's also a [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/235/) which covers advanced touch handling techniques.

Comment: Can i have sample code to check UIView1, UIView2 , UIView3 bound check ?

Comment: first `let views: [UIView]` be your views. and `let imageView: UIImageView` be your imageView. intersection goes something like this: `imageView.frame.intersects(views[0].frame)` and it returns a `Bool`